# Einkaufen: Wir nehmen die vier

Tags: meaning-in-context, demonstrative-pronoun

Dialog aus einem Kursbuch:

> Was kostet denn ein Poster?
>   Die hier kosten drei Euro 20.
>   Prima. Dann nehmen wir ***die*** vier.
>   Das macht 12 Euro 80.

Wieso wird gesagt: »die vier« und nicht einfach »vier«?

Comment: Allgemeiner Kommentar: "drei Euro 20" sieht sehr seltsam aus, ich wuerde "3,20 Euro" oder notfalls "drei Euro zwanzig" empfehlen.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold   Ja, *3,20 Euro* wäre die übliche *Schreib*weise. Katharina gibt aber mündliche Rede wieder, und in diesem Fall kann es durchaus angemessen sein, das gesprochene Wort auch so zu notieren, und dann ist es in der Tat korrekterweise *3 Euro 20*, auch wenn wir dieses Schriftbild nicht gewohnt sind. - Man könnte sich noch streiten, ob *drei Euro zwanzig* ebenfalls angemessen wäre. Auf jeden Fall aber würde ich entweder *3 Euro 20* oder *drei Euro zwanzig* schreiben, und nicht Zahlen und Buchstaben innerhalb des gleichen Preises mischen, wie es in einer der Antworten unten geschah.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich hab' damals in der Grundschule und im Gymnasium stets gesagt bekommen, dass man im Deutschen im Fließtext Zahlen bis (inklusive) zwölf ausschreibe und alles darüber in Ziffern. Vermutlich hat die Schreibweise "drei Euro 20" einen ähnlichen Hintergrund.

Answer (score 12):

In

> Wir nehmen *die* vier.

ist *»die«* ein Demonstrativpronomen, das ohne Bedeutungswechsel durch *»diese«* ersetzt werden kann:

> Wir nehmen *diese* vier.

Es ist damit also dasselbe Demonstrativpronomen, wie auch schon in dem vollständigen Satz davor:

> *Die* hier kosten drei Euro 20.
>   *Diese* hier kosten drei Euro 20.

Die Käufer haben offenbar vier bestimmte Poster ausgesucht, und wollen genau diese vier Exemplare kaufen.

Mit dem Satz

> Wir nehmen vier.

hätten die Käufer ausgedrückt, dass sie irgendwelche Poster aus dieser Preiskategorie kaufen wollen, dass ihnen aber egal ist, welche Motive auf den Postern abgebildet sein sollen.

Comment: Das gehört zwar in dieselbe Kategorie wie bei der Ersetzung durch *diese*, aber der Satz *Wir nehmen die vier* kann auch bedeuten, dass generell nur noch 4 Poster vorhanden sind, und daher *alle vier* (= *die vier*) genommen werden.